# Alter Keyboard Input

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard-events

For some of the reasons, keyboard setting must be altered. When user press a key form keyboard, Another character will be display in the edit text view. For example:

> A going to Z and Z going to be A.

how can this be done?

what I tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K){ 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "K is Pressed", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems did you encounter? Are you trying to affect an `EditText` in your own application, or are you trying to affect other applications?

Comment: `@Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "K is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
    return false;
   }`
I tried like this but it's doesn't work.